# Creating loop from 2 files in JS with subscription

Tags: web3js, javascript

I have 2 functions in 2 files.

```
1)const sql = require("./swap.test")
     var back = function Main(){
     web3Ws = new Web3(new Web3.providers.WebsocketProvider(""))

     var subscription = web3Ws.eth.subscribe('newBlockHeaders', function(error, result){})


.on("connected", function(subscriptionId){
    console.log("ID",subscriptionId);
})


.on("data", function(blockHeader){
 //Some code
await sql.jump(uniq,found) //jump to another file and function
subscription.unsubscribe(function(error, success){
          
        console.log('Successfully unsubscribed!');
        if(success) return
    })

}
```

---

```
2) const sort = require("./sort")
var jump = async function Final(arr,found){
  console.log("jump")
  for (let g of arr){
    
    await Borrow(g,found)
    
  }
   console.log("Go Back")
   sort.back
}
```

What I'm trying to do is to create an endless loop from following steps:

1. Getting data from blockchain with every block
2. Launch second file/function jump and stop receiving data from subscription while jump works.
   3)As soon as jump finishes it's task launch first file/function with subscription

I tried to launch this from both files, but I get only 1 loop. 2nd time `sort.back` doesn't launch anything

Answer (score 0):

I found the decision. But as always I think that it's not ideal and if somebody with experience explains why it's not possible to create a loop from 2 files, I'll appreciate it.
So, I created a third file that plays a role of middle man who tries to cheat the system.

2nd file)

```
 const Third = require("./launch")
    var jump = async function Final(arr,found){
      console.log("jump")
      for (let g of arr){
        
        await Borrow(g,found)
        console.log("HERE",g)
      }
       
       await Third.smallThird() // We are calling the function in the third file which launches the first file.
    }
```

3rd file(launch.js)

```
const {Main} = require("./sort") //function from 1st file


Main() //Calling function Main in the 1st file at the very beginning

var smallThird = function Third(){ //calling this function from the second file in order to launch our loop again in the first file.
console.log("third")
Main()
}

module.exports.smallThird = smallThird
```

So the way is following - 3rd file launches 1st file, 1st launches 2nd file and unsubscribes and 2nd launches 3rd file which launches 1st file. Loop created.